# Can I tp someone holding a specific item in minecraft windows 10 edition?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to tp someone holding a specific item (diamond sword), but I don't want it to be a `/clear @p[r=5] diamond_sword` and a `/tp @p x y z` command linked together because there will be more than one person in the room and only one will be holding a diamond sword, and the above command will just clear the sword and tp a person that may not be the holder of the sword. (I'm playing windows 10 edition on Xbox One)

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a certain item is in a player's inventory, or a specific inventory slot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371922/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-item-is-in-a-players-inventory-or-a-specific-inventor)

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a good way to inspect player inventories on bedrock. The closest you can manage is something like the following:

```
/enchant @a sharpness 1
```

This command would succeed if any player is holding *a* sword, but can't be made to be limited to a type of sword. It also can't be used to determine which player was holding the sword.

The following command will detect if someone has a diamond sword in their inventory, but not whether they're holding it.

```
/clear @p diamond_sword -1 0
```

If you're willing to compromise your design a little, you could have the player drop the sword and then detect it via the following command chain:

```
/execute @e[type=item,name="diamond_sword"] ~~~ tp @p x y z
```

This largely guarantees the player who had the sword is teleported because the item will be closest to the player who dropped it.

This leaves the player without a sword however and leaves the sword available for the other players to pick up. Both problems are solvable by additional command chains.

You can kill the sword to remove it so other players can't get it.

```
/kill @e[type=item,name="diamond_sword"]
```

And then give the teleported player back a diamond sword.

```
/replaceitem entity @p slot.weapon.mainhand 1 diamond_sword
```

This will have the side effect of restoring the sword's durability.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions work for Java Edition, I don't know if it's different in Console Edition. It definitely does not work for Pocket/Windows 10 Edition, because NBT doesn't work there.

---

You can use the `/scoreboard` command to tag players based on their NBT data. You would for example want this:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a add test {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:diamond_sword"}}
```

This everyone with "test" who is holding a diamond sword. Then you can just target players with the tag like this:

```
/tp @a[tag=test] <x> <y> <z>
```

Afterwards you have to remove the tag again so that it's ready to use the next time:

```
/scoreboard players tag @a[tag=test] remove test
```

Comment: i would use this command but sadly there is no /scoreboard command in windows 10 edition that i know works :( Thanks

Comment: Oh, I just read "XBox" and assumed Console Edition. You can play Windows 10 Edition on XBox? I didn't know that. I'll still leave the answer there, because maybe someone searches for this and finds my answer useful.

Comment: Btw, the answer to this question for Windows 10 edition is "it's impossible".

Comment: This only works for java but they can use a nbt editor