# How to tell if a certain item is in a player's inventory, or a specific inventory slot?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I am trying to create a challenge world where a certain item (in my example, a Netherite Sword) must be collected. Using commands, how can I if a player has it, and then run a command, for example, congratulating the winner?

I am also looking for a way to detect these items in a specific item slot. For example, a pair of Netherite Boots should run some commands to give the player the Speed effect when worn.

Is this possible? This question is specific to Bedrock Edition 1.16.

See also: [Testing for a certain dropped item](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/376566/250180)

---

[Browse more workarounds for getting/setting NBT in MCBE](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/334102/250180)

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 you edited the question to specify that testing for items in a specific slot was possible, but then don't seem to have actually added an answer saying how to do it.

Comment: @pppery I did not have time to make that answer, so I just drafted up a starter so you get an idea of what the answer details. Of course this is only preliminary and I will update this to be more professional and thorough once more is discovered about this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ### Outdated: pre-v1.18.30 only
>
> [ExpertCoder14’s answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/395443/188492) is better for v1.18.30 and up.

You can use [`/clear`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands/clear)`<player> netherite_sword -1 0`. The `-1` matches all data values and the `0` specifies the maximum number of items to clear (so none will be cleared). If the player has at least 1 netherite sword in their inventory, the command will output a success.

The success can be detected using a chain command block. Put the `/clear` any command block facing a conditional, always active, chain command block with the command that you want to execute if the player has a netherite sword.

Comment: fyi: Removed your assumption; it's correct.

Comment: Out of date! The `/clear` method has been superseded by `hasitem=`. It is more convenient than relying on command block output.

Answer (score 3):

> ## Up-to-date answer
>
> As of 1.18.30, the beta containing these features has been released.

The latest releases of Minecraft: Bedrock Edition have added a new target selector argument, `hasitem=`.

Syntax is as follows:

One item:

```
@a[hasitem={ item=<…>, count=<…>, data=<…>, location=<…>, slot=<…> }]
```

Multiple items:

```
@a[hasitem=[ { item=<…>, ……… }, { item=<…>, ……… } ]]
```

Fields are:

- `item`: Test for which item ID?
- `count`: Test for a certain count of this item. Can be a number or range (`5..10`)
- `data`: Test for the item's data value.
- `location` and `slot`: Only consider the slots specified to look for the item. `location` specifies the slot category, `slot` specifies the slot number.

If multiple sections are specified within `[ {}, {} ]`, all must pass.

Repeating any of `item`, `count`, `data`, `location`, or `slot` within the same section will not cause an error, however, only the *latter* one that is specified (furthest to the right) will be considered.