# How do I make an item where when a player holds it, it runs a slash command or function in a Minecraft bedrock addon?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

I am trying to make a paintbrush to assist me and my friends build a city.  My idea for the paintbrush is when held, it uses raycasting to place blocks where the entity is looking.  I can't use scripting because one of my friends is on Xbox and can't use scripting for some reason.  For the raycasting, I'm using a mcfunction.  How do I run a slash command or function when a player holds a specific item in Minecraft bedrock?  I think it's possible because it says in the Minecraft addon documentation entity events can call slash commands, other entity events, and MoLang.  I'm attaching a picture of that section of the documentation so you can see what I mean. [image] Here is what the image says in case the image fails to load.

> **Events**
>
> Events consist of three categories, all represented by a string:
>
> - Entity events
> - Slash Commands
> - MoLang Expressions
>
> In detail:
>
> Entity Events: Server side (behavior packs) only. Currently, we only
> support entity events to self, and these take the form "@s event".
> These are events declared in the events section of the entity
> definition file. For example, in the cat.json,
> "minecraft:ageable_grow_up" event causes the kitten to grow up. This
> would take the form of "@s minecraft:ageable_grow_up"
>
> Slash commands: Server side (behavior packs) only. Any slash command
> can be invoked, such as `/particle minecraft:example_smoke_puff ~ ~ ~`. The assumed entity for the slash command is the invoking entity,
> so this particular slash command will spawn a smoke puff effect at the
> entity's location.
>
> MoLang Expressions: This executes a MoLang expression. The primary
> usage is to set MoLang variables that can be used later. For example,
> a state transition might be looking at a particluar MoLang variable,
> and this expression could change that variable. A particle effect on
> the entity might change color due to MoLang variables that the effect
> uses for color tints. An animation to move an arm might use a MoLang
> variable that was set by an animation event.
>
> ```
> // entity event (behavior packs only), put the particular event name`
> after the @s "@s minecraft:entity_event"
>
> // slash command (behavior packs only), can be any server-side slash
> command // is invoked from the entity, so a teleport, for example,
> will teleport the entity by default "/tell @a this is a message"`
>
> // MoLang Expressions, executes a molang expression on the entity
> "variable.something_to_set = 3;"
> ```

Am I misunderstanding?  If not, how do I do this?  If any of this is unclear to you please ask questions in the comments.  Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a certain item is in a player's inventory, or a specific inventory slot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371922/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-item-is-in-a-players-inventory-or-a-specific-inventor)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you **cannot** check if a player is holding it, but you can check if a player *has* it on Bedrock Edition.

You can use this function to run it. Replace `stick`, `stone`, and `~ ~ ~` with what paintbrush item, what block you want, and the coordinates or where a player is looking, respectively.

Always active repeating command block

```
/clear <player> stick -1 0
```

This checks if a player has the paintbrush.
Chain conditional:

```
/tag <player> add brush
```

Chain conditionals:

```
/execute @a[tag=brush] setblock ~ ~ ~ stone
```

```
/tag  <player> remove brush
```

Replace `<player>` with the player you want to target. I hope this helps.