# Can I set command block to add poison effect?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can I set a command block in Minecraft to add poison effect to one player who didn't wear an armor?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a certain item is in a player's inventory, or a specific inventory slot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371922/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-item-is-in-a-players-inventory-or-a-specific-inventor)

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of that question,  since that one was about how to detect a particular condition, while this one seems to ask how to cause a particular effect to trigger when that condition is (not) detected.