# Helmet detection damaging system?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm trying to make a cool end of the world map and I want to make it so you take damage when not wearing a helmet. Could you help me out

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! On Minecraft commands questions, please see our [guide on what to do before asking a Minecraft commands question](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797), especially the part about “what you’ve tried so far”, and edit in the requested information to your post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a certain item is in a player's inventory, or a specific inventory slot?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/371922/how-to-tell-if-a-certain-item-is-in-a-players-inventory-or-a-specific-inventor)